# OSX: is there a way to disable the windows throttle on desktop change?

Tags: virtual-desktop, macos-highsierra, throttling

When I switch from virtual desktop A to virtual desktop B, my windows in A get throttled.

Is there a power saving feature to disable that throttling?

For example in chrome(ium), requestAnimationFrame is disabled until I switch back to the desktop A.
I've looked in chrome(ium) flags and found only `disable-background-throttle` but does not affect RAF.

On Windows, virtual desktops do not throttle windows in other desktops, so I thought it is an OS feature rather than a program one.

Comment: Windows andOS X are two very different operating systems you shouldn’t try and compare them

Comment: ikr but the desktop environment is a common feature. What I said was just an observation

Comment: It wasn't even a feature in Windows until Windows 10 it's not that common, and how they work between OS X, Solaris, Linux, and Windows are all different.